# C++ vector subscript out of range : Monotone Interpolation

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector, ide, interpolation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

// Function declarations
std::vector<double> wiki_mon_spline(const std::vector<double>& x, const std::vector<double>& y, const std::vector<double>& xq);

int main() {
    // Example usage
    std::vector<double> x = { 0,0.0208,0.0416,0.2,0.2208,0.2416,0.2416,0.2416,1.2416,1.2416,1.2624,1.2832,1.6416,1.6624,1.6832,1.6832,1.6832,2.6832,2.6832,2.704,2.7248,3.2832,3.304,3.3248,3.3248,3.3248,3.8248 };
    std::vector<double> y = { 0.404674,34.3471,31.8996,31.8996,6.74855,0.404674,0.404674,0.404674,0.404674,0.404674,30.3726,31.8996,31.8996,7.07452,0.404674,0.404674,0.404674,0.404674,0.404674,29.053,30.7901,30.7901,7.67308,0.404674,0.404674,0.404674,0.404674 };

    // Calculate xq in C++
    double dt = 0.0004;
    std::vector<double> xq;

    // Generate 10,000 equidistant samples
    double min_x = *std::min_element(x.begin(), x.end());
    double max_x = *std::max_element(x.begin(), x.end());
    for (double val = min_x; val <= max_x; val += dt)
    {
        xq.push_back(val);
    }

    std::cout << "Size of xq: " << xq.size() << std::endl;
    // Perform monotone cubic interpolation
    std::vector<double> result = wiki_mon_spline(x, y, xq);

    // Print the result
    for (size_t i = 0; i < xq.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << "Interpolation at xq[" << i << "]: " << xq[i] << "     " << result[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

std::vector<double> wiki_mon_spline(const std::vector<double>& x, const std::vector<double>& y, const std::vector<double>& xq) {
    int n = x.size();

    // Calculate slope at grid points
    std::vector<double> h(n - 1);
    std::vector<double> delta(n - 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
        h[i] = x[i + 1] - x[i];
        delta[i] = (y[i + 1] - y[i]) / h[i];
    }

    // Calculate slopes at interior points
    std::vector<double> m(n, 0.0);
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
        if (delta[i] * delta[i + 1] > 0) {
            double w1 = 2 * h[i + 1] + h[i];
            double w2 = h[i + 1] + 2 * h[i];
            m[i + 1] = (w1 + w2) / (w1 / delta[i] + w2 / delta[i + 1]);
        }
        else {
            m[i + 1] = 0.0; // Initialize to 0 if delta[i] and delta[i + 1] have opposite signs
        }
    }

    // Slope at end points
    m[0] = ((2 * h[0] + h[1]) * delta[0] - h[0] * delta[1]) / (h[0] + h[1]);

    if (m[0] * delta[0] <= 0) {
        m[0] = 0.0;
    }
    else if ((delta[0] * delta[1] <= 0) && (std::abs(m[0]) > std::abs(3 * delta[0]))) {
        m[0] = 3 * delta[0];
    }

    // Perform interpolation at query points xq
    std::vector<double> yq(xq.size(), 0.0);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < xq.size(); ++i) {
        // Find the interval containing xq[i]
        auto it = std::lower_bound(x.begin(), x.end(), xq[i]);
        if (it != x.end() && it != x.begin()) {
            int j = static_cast<int>(it - x.begin()) - 1;
            if (j < n - 1 && j >= 0) {
                // PCHIP interpolation formula
                double dx = xq[i] - x[j];
                double t = dx / h[j];
                double h00 = 2 * t * t * t - 3 * t * t + 1;
                double h10 = t * t * t - 2 * t * t + t;
                double h01 = -2 * t * t * t + 3 * t * t;
                double h11 = t * t * t - t * t;

                // Ensure monotonicity by considering signs
                double sign_delta = (delta[j] >= 0.0) ? 1.0 : -1.0;
                double sign_delta_next = (delta[j + 1] >= 0.0) ? 1.0 : -1.0;

                yq[i] = h00 * y[j] + sign_delta * h10 * h[j] + h01 * y[j + 1] + sign_delta_next * h11 * m[j];
            }
            else if (j < 0) {
                // Handle the case where xq[i] is beyond the first element of x
                yq[i] = y[0];
            }
            else {
                // Handle the case where xq[i] is beyond the last element of x
                yq[i] = y[n - 1];
            }
        }
    }

    return yq;
}
```

In the code above I'm performing Monotone Cubic Interpolation for 10000 samples (time 0.0004) but I'm facing error vector subscript out range however I change the limit or loop. Kindly help to resolve this?
What the x input the vector range should not fall out of range that's what I expect but with a sample input x= 0 to 5 y=0 to 4 it was working fine but with original input its throwing error "Vector subscript out of range"

Comment: Run your program under the debugger that comes with VS (are you really using VS2010?), it will stop your program at the point that failed. Inspect the state and see why it happened.

Comment: The "Calculate slopes" loop goes out of bounds on `h` and `delta`.

Comment: Given all the indexing with `+ 1`, there might be more problematic places. You need to be very careful when indexing with an added or subtracted loop index.

Comment: [`std::adjacent_difference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_difference) can help to eliminate some of the potential out of bounds

Comment: There are plenty of different types of opportunities to index a container out of bounds in that code.  Adding and subtracting `1` all over the place means a good chance of an "off by one" error.   Try checking EVERY index for validity BEFORE using it.  `wiki_mon_spline()` also uses `x.size()` to bound indices on `y` - which WILL be problematical if `y` and `x` have different sizes.